# How to query list of objects grouped by their count (by frequency of mentions for last day)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

The principe is like in StackOverFlow - every question has tags. And I need to display these tags by frequency of mentions for last day.

```
public List<TagDto> getAllTagsByCount() {
    List<TagDto> tagDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        tagDtos = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t.id, t.name FROM Tag t") // have no idea how to write such query
                .unwrap(Query.class)
                .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {
                    @Override
                    public Object transformTuple(Object[] objects, String[] strings) {
                        return TagDto.builder()
                                .id((Long) objects[0])
                                .name((String) objects[1])
                                .build();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public List transformList(List list) {
                        return list;
                    }
                })
                .getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tagDtos;
}
```

If u'll need some additional part of code, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably something like the following

```
    List<Tuple> tuple = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) FROM Tag t WHERE t.date BETWEEN :yesterday AND :tomorrow GROUP BY t.name")
        .setParameter("yesterday", LocalDateTime.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0))
        .setParameter("tomorrow", LocalDateTime.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).with(LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0))
        .getResultList();
```

You do not seem to have basic SQL knowledge though, so I would recommend you try to learn SQL first.